# How to filter columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a big dataset with more than 80 columns.

I wish to get a subset from dataset including the ***second column*** and columns from 10 to 40.

I know `dt.iloc[:,10:40]` gives me the column from **10** to **40**.

The question is, ***what is the easiest way to also include the second column to this subset as well?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.r_`

```
dt.iloc[:,np.r_[1,10:40]]
```